# Make unique array from different preg_match_all applied to array of string

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all

i've a logical problem that i don't know how to solve, i'm a lot confused about it.

I've an array composed in this way:

```
titoli[
    1 => 'NFL'
    2 => 'Johnny Depp'
    3 => 'Institute of Technology'
    4 => 'Another text'
]
```

Now, I need to apply different regex to that array, how can i do that and have a single final array?

For now i've written this:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($titoli);$i++)
{
    if(str_word_count($titoli[$i]) > preg_match_all('/([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)([\s][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+/', $titoli[$i]))
{
    preg_match('/([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)([\s][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+/', $titoli[$i], $result[$i]);
    $i++;
}
if(str_word_count($my_array[$i]) > preg_match_all('/^[A-Z][a-z]* [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*$/', $titoli[$x]) && preg_match_all('/^[A-Z][a-z]* [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*$/', $titoli[$i]) > 0) //controlla che nel titolo non siano state messe tutte le parole con l'iniziale maiuscola
{
    preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]* [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*$/', $titoli[$x], $result_b[$y], PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $y++;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show an example of what you want the result to look like.

Comment: Also, `preg_match_all` doesn't work on arrays, so some code showing what you are actually doing would help.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: You still didn't _show an example of what you want the result to look like_.

Comment: i've nothing to show, just need to know what is a good solution to apply different preg_match_all functions to all element of $titoli[] and then make a unique array with the result of each regex

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could merge the arrays then extract the unique values:

```
$merged = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

$unique = array_unique($merged);
```

Where `$array1`, `$array2` and `$array3` are the results of the `preg_match_all` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post an answer, but I have very little confidence that it will give you what you are looking for.  I tried to construct a method that mirrors your intent -- but I could be dead wrong.

Input:

```
$titoli=[
    1 => 'NFL',
    2 => 'Johnny Depp',
    3 => 'Institute of Technology',
    4 => 'Another text'
];
```

Method:

```
foreach($titoli as $t){
    if($t==strtoupper($t)){  // every letter is uppercase
        $result['acronyms'][]=$t;
    }elseif($t==ucwords(strtolower($t))){  // every word starts with an uppercase letter
        $result['names'][]=$t;
    }else{  // has at least one word begins with a lowercase letter
        $result['other'][]=$t;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'acronyms' => 
  array (
    0 => 'NFL',
  ),
  'names' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Johnny Depp',
  ),
  'other' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Institute of Technology',
    1 => 'Another text',
  ),
)
```